# Removing keyboard focus from edit control

Tags: c, winapi, controls, edit

Is there anyway to kill the focus from edit control whenever it receives a keyboard focus?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create an edit control which the user can't edit.  Why not use a label if you don't want users editting or making it read-only

Answer (score 7):

Create it with the ES_READONLY style, or call EnableWindow(hctl,FALSE); to prevent the control receiving focus.